# Golang - Combined, dot-separated functions

Tags: go

There are constructs like these in Go which I do not fully understand:

- `rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())`
- `tmpl, err := template.New("name").Parse(...)`

So functions ending with a DOT and "concatenating" another function directly after the DOT.

How can I recognise when this can be done? How is that called in Go?

Comment: It's not concatenation. That's a [selector expression](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Selectors). If a function or a method returns a single value of a type that has methods then you can call those methods immediately by using the selector expression. For example `time.Now()` returns a value of type `time.Time` which has a method called `UnixNano()` so `time.Now().UnixNano()` is the same as `t := time.Now(); t.UnixNano()`.

Comment: This is commonly called "method chaining" in many languages. You're simply calling a method on the returned value. For instance, the first example could be written like so: https://go.dev/play/p/tgEmzhgfZu1

Comment: It will be easy to interpret, if you identify the return type of the first part `time.Now()` and `template.New("name")`, and that return type is likely to be defined as a receiver to the next method. pkg.go.dev is your friend!

Answer (score 0):

It's called method chaining as stated in the comments.

For example, we have a `Graph` type as such:

```golang
type Graph struct {
    Vertices      int
    AdjacencyList [][]int
}

func NewGraph(vertices int) *Graph {
    return &Graph{
        Vertices:      vertices,
        AdjacencyList: make([][]int, vertices),
    }
}

func (g *Graph) AddEdge(v, w int) {
    g.AdjacencyList[v] = append(g.AdjacencyList[v], w)
}
```

Note that the constructor `NewGraph()` returns a `Graph` object. And the method `AddEdge` can be called when it is of type `Graph`.

Normally when we want to use it in our function, we will call the constructor, then chain the other methods.

```golang
func main() {
    NewGraph(5).AddEdge(0, 1).AddEdge(0, 2)
}
```

`NewGraph(5)` is initializing the graph with 5 vertices, and returns the `Graph` object. Then by chaining `AddEdge(0,1)` we are directly adding edges to this `Graph` object.